# Facebook, Pinterest ignoring og:image, but debugger says everything's fine

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, pinterest

When I paste https://testing.grabble.co.uk/user/index/user/ben.mu into Facebook, for some reason it's picking the banner image from the top of the page instead of the image indicated in the og:image meta tag.

However, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftesting.grabble.co.uk%2Fuser%2Findex%2Fuser%2Fben.mu indicates that everything  is being pulled through correctly. Anyone got any ideas why this might be? The image is 200x200, which as I understand it should be large enough for Facebook to not ignore it.

Additionally, Pinterest seems to ignore all our og:image tags as well, even when the images being set are 450x450 or larger. I suspect this is related.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Facebook will take a larger, more detailed image over the one you've indicated in the og:image property if the og:image URL doesn't appear in the page as an actual `<img/>` element. Solution to this was to switch the banner image from being an `<img/>` tag to a background-image:url() CSS property. Everything now works as expected, including on Pinterest.